# How to estimate one's facebook reach by its likes and shares?

Tags: facebook

Are there any existing models how to estimate / calculate the reach of a facebook post (not my own) by its interactions (likes / shares) and the likes of the page in general?

Certainly the reach will differ widely if  a user with 1000 friends shares the post, or if a user with 10 friends shares the post - BUT:

I think for bigger facebook pages (let's say the nba or something similar) there should be some kind of average.

I tried looking up google scholar but couldn't find any research about it.

Is something like that possible?

Comment: This question may be better at [webapps.se]

Comment: Agreed. While Facebook can be a digital face for communities, "social media only" questions are not in scope here.

Comment: I think it's also important to consider what the goal is. Does a number like 100 or 1000 or 10,000 mean something to you or to someone else in your business? I ask because in some cases a business leader will want to see numbers to justify investments in social media tools, training or content spend, or will try to map out how many likes = how many sales. It just doesn't work that way, unfortunately. If that's not what you're trying to do, ManuKaracho, maybe someone else might find this answer helpful. : )

Answer (score -2):

There's a website that indexes that and compares it to other people: http://klout.com

Klout measure how many friends, and what topics you talk about, and who likes your posts, and who shares your posts